# Posting data to asp.net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to figure out the new ASP.NET Web API.

So far I've been able to create this method signature and connect to it just fine and get a valid response...

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage CreateAccount()
```

I am able to send a request to this method with fiddler and have verified that it is receiving the request.

However, when I try to pass data is when I am running into a problem.

The first thing I tried was...

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage CreateAccount([FromBody]string email, [FromBody]string password)
```

And I type

email:xyz,password:abc

into the body of the request in fiddler.  When I do this I get a 500 error stating

'Can't bind multiple parameters ('email' and 'password') to the request's content.'

I have also tried this as a method signature...

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage CreateAccount([FromBody]UserAccountRequestData data)
```

with the UserAccountRequestData being a simple POCO

```
public class UserAccountRequestData
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

And I put

{Email:xyz,Password:abc}

or

data:{Email:xyz,Password:abc}

into the body of the request.  In both cases trying to populate the POCO I am able to reach the method while debugging, but the data object is always null.

I need to understand how to create API methods that accept both strongly typed POCOs and others that accept multiple primitive types like strings and ints.

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` and then provide valid JSON.

```
{"Email":"xyz","Password":"abc"}
```

Comment: +1 for Darrel Miller answer. Also you can refer to the answer given for [Sending JSON object to Web API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870161/sending-json-object-to-web-api). It does give you a sample code for your question.