# ContentType application/json in ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

I'm building my first WebAPI using ASP.NET MVC 4 WebAPI.

The requests must be sent using the application/json ContentType with utf-8 as the character set.

My POST method looks like this:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

Whenever I'm sending a POST request the parameter 'value' is null. The request body contains Json: `{ "name":"test" }`.

What I prefer is to have the parameter of the Post method to be either a string containing the Json or be of type JObject (from the JSON.NET library). How do I accomplish this? And is this even possible?

Comment: Of course. First of all, rename value to 'name'

Comment: That doesn't work. The value of the parameter is still null. The Json will eventually be something like { "name1": [ {}, {} ], "name2": [], "name3":"some value" }. I don't want the Json to be deserialized into an object by the system itself. I want to do that myself.

Comment: If you want to controls deserialization, add a Custom media type formatter for JSON. Otherwise, is it an option for you to send the body as x-www-form-urlencoded string instead and then to create an object from that?

Comment: If you are sending a JSON object to the Web API service, you can create a POCO model containing "name1, "name2", etc., then you can change your method as public HttpResponseMessage Post(YourObject object) {}   After that you can deserialize it in the method using the usual JSON.NET parse method. Are you sending your JSON from JavaScript, can you show the code?

Comment: Here's a good example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870161/sending-json-object-to-web-api

Comment: Joanna, when adding a custom media type formatter for Json, am I still able to use the application/json content-type? I found a tutorial on media type formatters here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters. Is this what you mean?

Comment: ADNow, yes that's also a solution. I'll see which one I go with. Thanks! I'm using Fiddler or Firefox Poster to send a request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to grab the raw string directly from `Request.Content`:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
{
    string value = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

There is a way to make ASP.NET Web Api treat your request body as string content, but in order to do that the content must be in `=value` format, in your case something like this:

```
={ "name":"test" }
```

You can achieve something like this with following jQuery code (for example):

```
$.post('api/values', '=' + JSON.stringify({ name: 'test' }));
```

In that case you can use signature from your question.

In the end there is always an option of creating your own `MediaTypeFormatter` to replace the default `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` and make it always deserialize the content into `JObject`. You can read more about creating and registering `MediaTypeFormatter` [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/18/using-json-net-with-asp-net-web-api.aspx).