# Posting JSON data via jQuery to ASP .NET MVC 4 controller action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm having trouble trying to pass a complex JSON object to an MVC 4 controller action.  As the JSON content is variable, I don't want MVC to map individual properties/elements of the JSON to parameters in the action method's parameter list.  I just want to get the data as a single JSON string parameter in the controller action.

Here's the signature of my action method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public string ConvertLogInfoToXml(string jsonOfLog)
```

And here's my attempt to post some JSON data, from my browser:

```
    data = {prop: 1, myArray: [1, "two", 3]}; 
    //'data' is much more complicated in my real application
    json = {jsonOfLog: data};

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "Home/ConvertLogInfoToXml",
        data: JSON.stringify(json),
        success: function (returnPayload) {
            console && console.log ("request succeeded");
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console && console.log ("request failed");
        },
        dataType: "xml",
        contentType: "application/json",            
        processData: false,
        async: false
    });
```

When I hit my breakpoint at the beginning of the ConvertLogInfoToXML method, jsonOfLog is null.

If I change what 'json' variable is set to in the JavaScript to have the jsonOfLog property be a simple string, e.g. :

```
json = { jsonOfLog: "simple string" };
```

then when my breakpoint at the beginning of the ConvertLogInfoToXML method is hit, jsonOfLog is the value of the string (e.g. "simple string").

I tried changing the type of the jsonOfLog parameter in the action method to be of type object:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public string ConvertLogInfoToXml(object jsonOfLog)
```

Now, with the original JavaScript code (where I'm passing a more complex 'data' object), jsonOfLog gets the value of {object}.  But the debugger doesn't show any more details in a watch window, and I don't know what methods I can use to operate on this variable.

How do I pass JSON data to a MVC controller, where the data passed is a stringified complex object?

Thanks,
Notre

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578814/how-to-receive-json-in-a-mvc-5-action-method-as-a-paramter

Comment: Check this: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Posting-JSON-Data-to-ASP-NET-MVC-with-Code-Examples

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is your `dataType` and the format of your `data` parameter.  I just tested this in a sandbox and the following works:

C#

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string ConvertLogInfoToXml(string jsonOfLog)
    {
        return Convert.ToString(jsonOfLog);
    }
```

javascript

```
<input type="button" onclick="test()"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function test() {
            data = { prop: 1, myArray: [1, "two", 3] };
            //'data' is much more complicated in my real application
            var jsonOfLog = JSON.stringify(data);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'text',
                url: "Home/ConvertLogInfoToXml",
                data: "jsonOfLog=" + jsonOfLog,
                success: function (returnPayload) {
                    console && console.log("request succeeded");
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    console && console.log("request failed");
                },

                processData: false,
                async: false
            });
        }

    </script>
```

Pay special attention to `data`, when sending text, you need to send a variable that matches the name of your parameter.  It's not pretty, but it will get you your coveted unformatted string.

When running this, jsonOfLog looks like this in the server function:

```
    jsonOfLog   "{\"prop\":1,\"myArray\":[1,\"two\",3]}"    string
```

The HTTP POST header:

```
Key Value
Request POST /Home/ConvertLogInfoToXml HTTP/1.1
Accept  text/plain, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
Referer http://localhost:50189/
Accept-Language en-US
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
Host    localhost:50189
Content-Length  42
DNT 1
Connection  Keep-Alive
Cache-Control   no-cache
Cookie  EnableSSOUser=admin
```

The HTTP POST body:

```
jsonOfLog={"prop":1,"myArray":[1,"two",3]}
```

The response header:

```
Key Value
Cache-Control   private
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Date    Fri, 28 Jun 2013 18:49:24 GMT
Response    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server  Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version 4.0
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles   =?UTF-8?B?XFxwc2ZcaG9tZVxkb2N1bWVudHNcdmlzdWFsIHN0dWRpbyAyMDEyXFByb2plY3RzXE12YzRQbGF5Z3JvdW5kXE12YzRQbGF5Z3JvdW5kXEhvbWVcQ29udmVydExvZ0luZm9Ub1htbA==?=
```

The response body:

```
{"prop":1,"myArray":[1,"two",3]}
```

Comment: What you suggested _does_ work (with a **problem**).  But not because of the data property of the ajax object.  Instead, it is the removal of the contentType property.  By removing it, the default of "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is used.  The problem with this is, once the data posted gets 'large', it gets truncated -- I think by the server.  I found the same solution early and was very happy with it until I ran into that problem.

Comment: There is a 48KB limit on `application/x-ww-form-urlencoded`. You normally need to fall-back to `multipart/form-data` for larger data sets... but you're right.  In this instance it does not work.  You may be hitting the square peg/round hole point in the architecture.  I'll be curious if you work something out as it will be a nice tidbit to know in the future.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, and for spending the time on my question.  Your solution is good, except for the large data set issue (which was not specified in the original question).  Maybe I should enter a new question, then you can get credit for this one...

Comment: After banging my head further, I could not find a way to make this work other than the way you described.  This leads to the truncation issue.  I ended up switching to Web API.  Doing so, I could pass my stringified JSON via a regular application/json content type and I didn't run into the length issue.  I don't know why ASP .NET MVC controller actions doesn't work this way (I'm guessing the model binder is getting in the way).  I'm going to accept your answer, with the note re: content length.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find your answer if you refer to this post: [Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object)

There are various ways of achieving what you want here. The System.Web.Helpers.Json approach (a few answers down) seems to be the simplest.

Comment: Thanks Acorn.  I think my key problem is getting the parameter in my action method "jsonOfLog" to get a non-null value, when I have it as type string.  If I could just get the stringified JSON in my action method without a bunch of translation (I guess the model binder is getting in the way), I think I'd be set.

Comment: If you want to work with strings, using the solution that J Torres provided will work. However, assuming you need to do anything meaningful with that data, I think it's much nicer to work with data that is deserialized.

Comment: Generally speaking, you're absolutely right - having the binder automatically create types is usually desirable.  If you see the comments, J Torres solution is perfect, except I run into problems when a 'large' set of data is passed.

Answer (score 2):

## VB.NET VERSION

Okay, so I have just spent several hours looking for a viable method for posting **multiple parameters** to an MVC 4 WEB API, but most of what I found was either for a 'GET' action or just flat out did not work. However, I finally got this working and I thought I'd share my solution.

1. Use NuGet packages to download `JSON-js json2` and `Json.NET`. Steps to install NuGet packages:

   (1) In Visual Studio, go to **Website** > **Manage NuGet Packages...** [image]

   (2) Type json (or something to that effect) into the search bar and find `JSON-js json2` and `Json.NET`. Double-clicking them will install the packages into the current project.[image]

   (3) NuGet will automatically place the json file in `~/Scripts/json2.min.js` in your project directory. Find the json2.min.js file and drag/drop it into the head of your website. **Note**: for instructions on installing .js (javascript) files, read **[this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17725361/turning-two-elements-visible-hidden-in-the-same-div/17726550#17726550)**.
2. Create a class object containing the desired parameters. You will use this to access the parameters in the API controller. Example code:

   ```
   Public Class PostMessageObj

   Private _body As String
   Public Property body As String
       Get
           Return _body
       End Get
       Set(value As String)
           _body = value
       End Set
   End Property


   Private _id As String
   Public Property id As String
       Get
           Return _id
       End Get
       Set(value As String)
           _id = value
       End Set
   End Property
   End Class
   ```
3. Then we setup the actual MVC 4 Web API controller that we will be using for the POST action. In it, we will use Json.NET to deserialize the string object when it is posted. Remember to use the appropriate namespaces. Continuing with the previous example, here is my code:

   ```
   Public Sub PostMessage(<FromBody()> ByVal newmessage As String)

   Dim t As PostMessageObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of PostMessageObj)(newmessage)

   Dim body As String = t.body
   Dim i As String = t.id

   End Sub
   ```
4. Now that we have our API controller set up to receive our stringified JSON object, we can call the POST action freely from the client-side using $.ajax; Continuing with the previous example, here is my code (replace localhost+rootpath appropriately):

   ```
   var url = 'http://<localhost+rootpath>/api/Offers/PostMessage';
   var dataType = 'json'
   var data = 'nothn'
   var tempdata = { body: 'this is a new message...Ip sum lorem.',
       id: '1234'
   }
   var jsondata = JSON.stringify(tempdata)
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: { '': jsondata},
       success: success(data),
       dataType: 'text'
   });
   ```

As you can see we are basically building the JSON object, converting it into a string, passing it as a single parameter, and then rebuilding it via the JSON.NET framework. I did not include a return value in our API controller so I just placed an arbitrary string value in the `success()` function.

---

## Author's notes

This was done in Visual Studio 2010 using ASP.NET 4.0, WebForms, VB.NET, and MVC 4 Web API Controller. For anyone having trouble integrating MVC 4 Web API with VS2010, you can download the patch to make it possible. You can download it from Microsoft's **[Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30683)**.

Here are some additional references which helped (mostly in C#):

- [Using jQuery to Post FromBody Parameters](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/)
- [Sending JSON object to Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870161/sending-json-object-to-web-api)
- And of course J Torres's answer was the last piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

//simple json object in asp.net mvc

```
var model = {"Id": "xx", "Name":"Ravi"};
$.ajax({    url: 'test/[ControllerName]',
                        type: "POST",
                        data: model,
                        success: function (res) {
                            if (res != null) {
                                alert("done.");
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (res) {

                        }
                    });


//model in c#
public class MyModel
{
 public string Id {get; set;}
 public string Name {get; set;}
}

//controller in asp.net mvc


public ActionResult test(MyModel model)
{
 //now data in your model 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some months ago I ran into an odd situation where I also needed to send some Json-formatted date back to my controller. Here's what I came up with after pulling my hair out:

My class looks like this :

```
public class NodeDate
{
    public string nodedate { get; set; }
}
public class NodeList1
{
    public List<NodeDate> nodedatelist { get; set; }
}
```

and my c# code as follows :

```
        public string getTradeContribs(string Id, string nodedates)
    {            
        //nodedates = @"{""nodedatelist"":[{""nodedate"":""01/21/2012""},{""nodedate"":""01/22/2012""}]}";  // sample Json format
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer ser = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        NodeList1 nodes = (NodeList1)ser.Deserialize(nodedates, typeof(NodeList1));
        string thisDate = "";
        foreach (var date in nodes.nodedatelist)
        {  // iterate through if needed...
            thisDate = date.nodedate;
        }   
    }
```

and so I was able to Deserialize my nodedates Json object parameter in the "nodes" object; naturally of course using the class "NodeList1" to make it work.

I hope this helps....
Bob

Comment: Thanks Bob for your reply.  How did your client code look that posted (?) nodedates to getTradeContribs?  My key problem seems to be that as soon as I get to the controller action, the parameter (e.g. nodedates) is set to null if it contains something other than a basic string.  Was nodedates "stringified" on the calling side?

Answer (score 0):

Well my client side (a cshtml file) was using DataTables to display a grid (now using Infragistics control which are great).
And once the user clicked on the row, I captured the row event and the date associated with that record in order to go back to the server and make additional server-side requests for trades, etc.
And no - I DID NOT stringify it...

The DataTables def started as this (leaving lots of stuff out), and the click event is seen below where I PUSH onto my Json object :

```
    oTablePf = $('#pftable').dataTable({         // INIT CODE
             "aaData": PfJsonData,
             'aoColumnDefs': [                     
                { "sTitle": "Pf Id", "aTargets": [0] },
                { "sClass": "**td_nodedate**", "aTargets": [3] }
              ]
              });

   $("#pftable").delegate("tbody tr", "click", function (event) {   // ROW CLICK EVT!! 

        var rownum = $(this).index(); 
        var thisPfId = $(this).find('.td_pfid').text();  // Find Port Id and Node Date
        var thisDate = $(this).find('.td_nodedate').text();

         //INIT JSON DATA
        var nodeDatesJson = {
            "nodedatelist":[]
        };

         // omitting some code here...
         var dateArry = thisDate.split("/");
         var nodeDate = dateArry[2] + "-" + dateArry[0] + "-" + dateArry[1];

         nodeDatesJson.nodedatelist.push({ nodedate: nodeDate });

           getTradeContribs(thisPfId, nodeDatesJson);     // GET TRADE CONTRIBUTIONS 
    });
```