# Tagging Input for that works with ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, controls, tagging

I'm playing with jquery tagit plugin at http://webspirited.com/tagit/. It's perfect for what I need but I can't get it to update the asp:BulletList because it's a server control.

I know there are workarounds by using ajax/updatepanel but I need something will work the the same way as other controls during the postback.

Are there any controls for asp.net does allows tagging?

Answer (score 0):

I also used jQuery tagit when building my site...and I ran into the same issues you are describing. I managed to overcome all the issues and get it to work, but it was definitely not developer-friendly. In the end, we replaced the update panels with ASP.NET Web API's for partial page rendering **(this is how you should be doing it by the way)**, and created  our own tagging plugin. The jQuery Tagit plugin definitely has a few bugs, so creating our own was ultimately the best solution. Here's the problems you'll run into with jQuery Tagit and Update Panels...

---

**Javascript loses references on update panel refresh**

Firstly, when the update panel refreshes, you lose all javascript references. You can refresh these references by redefining them at the end of the page request. You can use a page request manager for accomplishing this. Here is an example:

Add a function to your javascript that redefines all javascript references located within the update panel:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function contentPageEvents(){
        var myTagitDiv = $('.myTagitDiv')
    }
</script>
```

Then at the end of your page you can add this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(contentPageEvents);
</script>
```

---

**ASP.NET changes the IDs of its server-side controls**

In order to reference an ASP.NET control, you must either use `ClientIdMode="Static"`, or reference the CSS class of the control rather than the ID. ASP.NET controls have almost the same level of customizibility as normal HTML controls as long as you use the CssClass attribute effectively.

---

### Don't use Update Panels

In the end, you really shouldn't be using update panels at all. The ASP.NET update panel is designed to simulate partial page rendering, but does not actually perform it. If you plan to build a decent web site and want to use partial page rendering, you should start looking into using the new Web API Controller class that comes with MVC 4. This amazing tool can be easily implemented in a Web Forms project. It is built-in in Visual Studio 2012, and can be downloaded for use in Visual Studio 2010. Here is a link to a tutorial on how to create a web api that can post items to a database:

[asp.net mvc - Posting JSON data via jQuery to ASP.NET MVC 4 controller action (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18996012/1751792)