# Send data to MVC controller using JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I am using JQuery Ajax to make a simple call to an ASP.NET MVC controller. Here is my code

```
   function postdata(idno) {
   console.log(idno);

   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/IM/GetMessages",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',            
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'fUserId': idno }), 
        success: function (data) { /*CODE*/

    });}
```

The controller looks like this

```
     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult GetMessages(decimal? fUserId)
     {
        var list = WebUtility.IMMessages.Where(p =>
            (p.ToUserId == Session.UserId  && (!fUserId.HasValue || fUserId.HasValue && p.User == fUserId.Value)))
            .OrderBy(p => p.CreatedDateTime)
            .Select(p => new { MessageId = p.RecordId, MessageBody = p.Description1 });

        return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
```

The **problem** is that my data doesn't pass to my controller, "null" passes instead. how can I correct this issue? I am watching "idno" on console and everything seems to be OK.

Comment: Try looking at the network tab of your browser to see what is being sent in the request, and try changing the parameter to a non nullable decimal (though I wouldn't think that would matter).

Comment: On network tab, everything seemed to be ok, actually now the code i gave you is working now, obviously i focused on wrong part of my code. Thanks for your that much quick answer, and sorry for my that much late response.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search found a lot of materials on Stack Overflow relating to this issue.  Pulled from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17371494/1463649), try changing this:

`data: JSON.stringify({ 'fUserId': idno }),`

to this:

```
data: "fUserId=" + JSON.stringify(idno),
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to convert a single parameter into a JSON if you ask me. Instead just do this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/IM/GetMessages?fUserId=" + idno,
    dataType: 'json',            
    success: function (data) { /*CODE*/
});
```

This way you can still get back JSON but you pass single parameter value. Now if you really need to send an object I don't see anything wrong with your code. You might want to declare a javascript variable and turn it into a json object like this:

```
var myVar = { fUserId: idno };
```

and then use that in your ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/IM/GetMessages",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',            
    data: JSON.stringify(myVar), 
    success: function (data) { /*CODE*/

});
```

I do this daily and it works fine for me with both nullable and non-nullable types...

Comment: I am really glad that you have given a detailed answer. You were right that there was nothing wrong with my code, it is working now, actually i don't know what the real problem was.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to do this:

```
data: { fUserId: idno }
```

Answer (score 0):

I **changed nothing** with my code, **but it is working** now. I think there was another problem affecting passing data. I changed many things generally in my code and now actually i don't know what the problem exactly was. Maybe the solution was just rebooting my web application and clearing all caches and cookies in web browser.