# cannot pass paramerters as JSON to mvc controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass an `id` and an `object` which has four properties to an action controller but unfortunately it is not getting through and I get the following error.

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'batchID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult GetItems(Int32, Ebiquity.Reputation.Neptune.Web.Models.MyWorkFilterModel)' in 'Ebiquity.Reputation.Neptune.Web.Controllers.MyWorkController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>
> Parameter name: parameters

The JSON being passed is:

```
{
    "batchID": 21610,
    "filter":
    {
        "issueNo": "1",
        "messageNo": "2",
        "itemDate": "Wed, 05 Feb 2014 00:00:00 GMT",
        "mediaName":"3"
    }
};
```

The ajax call:

```
self.GetItems = function (batchID, issueNo, messageNo, itemDate, mediaName) {

    var filter = {
        issueNo: issueNo,
        messageNo: messageNo,
        itemDate: itemDate,
        mediaName: mediaName
    };
        
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/MyWork/GetItems",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            batchID: batchID,
            filter: filter
        }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {

            self.Items([]);
            if (result.Items != null) {
                var tempItems = ko.mapping.fromJS(result.Items, mappingOptions);
                self.Items.push.apply(self.Items, tempItems());
            }
        }
    });
};
```

The controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetItems(int batchID, MyWorkFilterModel filter)
{
    using (var rep = new WorkRepository(CurrentUser))
    {
        return Json(rep.GetBatch(batchID, filter), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

The filter model:

```
public class MyWorkFilterModel
{
    public int? IssueNo { get; set; }
    public int? MessageNo { get; set; }
    public string MediaName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ItemDate { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the contenttype property of the ajax call and instead of GET I used POST and it worked.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/MyWork/GetItems",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                batchID: batchID,
                filter: filter
            }),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {
                }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to change type of your AJAX call to POST instead of GET. Data parameters will not be send with GET requests.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your `batchID` is null. Either set it as `0` in javascript or make it `nullable` in action

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetItems(int? batchID, MyWorkFilterModel filter)
{

}
```

Comment: batchID is mandatory, Its not null, it wont be passed to controller if it fails the null check.

Answer (score 0):

We have a lot of discussions here like this (see the below link)

[Posting JSON data via jQuery to ASP .NET MVC 4 controller action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370062/posting-json-data-via-jquery-to-asp-net-mvc-4-controller-action)

Try like below Ajax DataType:

```
self.GetItems = function (batchID, issueNo, messageNo, itemDate, mediaName) {

    var filter = {
        issueNo: issueNo,
        messageNo: messageNo,
        itemDate: itemDate,
        mediaName: mediaName
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/MyWork/GetItems",
        dataType: 'text',
        data: "param=" + JSON.stringify({
            batchID: batchID,
            filter: filter
        }),
        success: function (result) {
            self.Items([]);
            if (result.Items != null) {
                var tempItems = ko.mapping.fromJS(result.Items, mappingOptions);
                self.Items.push.apply(self.Items, tempItems());
            }
        }
    });
};
```

The controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetItems(String Param)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to make IssueNo and MessageNo as integers instead of strings. And use `POST` instead of `GET`.

If you have to use GET, you may pass the parameters as a part of the url only!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Semao, if you want that kind of JSON you need to use POST. Since your posting the JSON in that way, I guess you just have a typo and intend to use POST.

If you really want GET, you need to pass the values in the URL.

In your case, youneed to add:

```
[FromUri]
```

before the objects.

Example:

```
public class QueryObj
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public Result Get([FromUri] QueryObj queryObj)
{...}

http://.../query?Id=1&Name=test
```