# MVC data from View to Controller with JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i need your help please. I have created a JQXGrid with MVC from two different tables "Prodotti" and "Scheda". I load data from controller with entity framework in this way:

```
public JsonResult GetProducts()
{
    try
    {
        var dbResult = db.PartnerProducts.ToList();
        var products = from e in dbResult
                       select new
                       {
                           e.Id,
                           e.PartnerId, 
                           e.Title,
                           e.Price,
                           e.Quantity,
                           e.Status,
                           e.DateCreated,   
                           e.Photo,
                           e.ShortDescription,
                           e.LongDescription,
                           e.cat,   
                           e.lotto, 
                           e.nomeproduttore,    
                           e.origine,
                           e.idcategoria,   
                           e.apezzo,
                           e.pesomedio,
                           e.prezzoscontato,
                           e.IdSchedaProdotto, 
                           e.Priority,  
                           e.PartnerOwner, 
                           e.Deperibile,
                           e.inbustati,
                           e.confezionati,
                           nomeCategoria = e.categoriaprodottopersonalizzato?.nome,
                           sottotitolo = e.SchedaProdotto?.Sottotitolo,
                           provenienza = e.SchedaProdotto?.Provenienza,
                           curiosita = e.SchedaProdotto?.Curiosita,
                           proprieta = e.SchedaProdotto?.Proprieta,
                           periodo = e.SchedaProdotto?.Periodo,
                           conservazione = e.SchedaProdotto?.Conservazione,
                           foto = e.SchedaProdotto?.Foto,   
                           titolo = e.SchedaProdotto?.Titolo,
                           visibile = e.SchedaProdotto?.Visibile,
                           link = e.SchedaProdotto?.Link,   
                           viaAerea = e.SchedaProdotto?.ViaAerea,
                           nome = e.SchedaProdotto?.Nome
                       };
      }

      return Json(products, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And i load all data in JQuery table with this code:

```
datafields: [{ name: 'Id' },
                { name: 'PartnerId' },
                { name: 'Title' },
                { name: 'Price' },
                { name: 'Quantity' },
                { name: 'Status' },
                { name: 'DateCreated' },
                { name: 'Photo' },
                { name: 'ShortDescription' },
                { name: 'LongDescription' },
                { name: 'cat' },
                { name: 'lotto' },
                { name: 'nomeproduttore' },
                { name: 'origine' },
                { name: 'idcategoria' },
                { name: 'apezzo' },
                { name: 'pesomedio' },
                { name: 'prezzoscontato' },
                { name: 'IdSchedaProdotto' },
                { name: 'Priority' },
                { name: 'PartnerOwner' },
                { name: 'Deperibile' },
                { name: 'inbustati' },
                { name: 'confezionati' },
                { name: 'nomeCategoria' },
                { name: 'sottotitolo' },
                { name: 'provenienza' },
                { name: 'curiosita' },
                { name: 'proprieta' },
                { name: 'periodo' },
                { name: 'conservazione' },
                { name: 'foto' },
                { name: 'titolo' },
                { name: 'visibile' },
                { name: 'link' },
                { name: 'viaAerea' },
                { name: 'nome' }
```

And the load of data works well. Now the problem is when i want to add new data...i read data from column with this function:

```
 addrow: function (rowid, rowdata, position, commit) {
            // synchronize with the server - send insert command
            // call commit with parameter true if the synchronization with the server is successful
            // and with parameter false if the synchronization failed.
            // you can pass additional argument to the commit callback which represents the new ID if it is generated from a DB.
            var data = "add=true&Id=" + rowdata.Id + "&PartnerId=" + rowdata.PartnerId +  "&Title=" + rowdata.Title + "&Price=" + rowdata.Price + "&Quantity=" + rowdata.Quantity + "&Status=" + rowdata.Status;
            data = data + "&Photo=" + rowdata.Photo + "&cat=" + rowdata.cat + "&lotto=" + rowdata.lotto + "&origine=" + rowdata.origine + "&idcategoria=" + rowdata.idcategoria;
            data = data + "&apezzo=" + rowdata.apezzo + "&pesomedio=" + rowdata.pesomedio + "&prezzoscontato=" + rowdata.prezzoscontato;
            data = data + "&IdSchedaProdotto=" + rowdata.IdSchedaProdotto + "&Deperibile=" + rowdata.Deperibile + "&confezionati=" + rowdata.confezionati + "&nomeCategoria=" + rowdata.nomeCategoria;
            data = data + "&provenienza=" + rowdata.provenienza + "&viaAerea=" + rowdata.viaAerea + "&periodo=" + rowdata.periodo + "&curiosita=" + rowdata.curiosita;
            data = data + "&proprieta=" + rowdata.proprieta + "&conservazione=";
            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'AddProducts',
                data: data,
                success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                    // update command is executed.
                }
            });
```

And i want to realobarate this function from server here:

```
public bool AddProducts(PartnerProduct product)
```

The `AddProducts` function work fine but in the object Product i can retrieve only value from table Product, such as title or price...How can i save in Jquery values for table "scheda" that are empty in this server-side function?

For example i load data with

`titolo = e.SchedaProdotto?.Provenienza,`

Pass it to server side with

```
"&provenienza=" + rowdata.provenienza
```

but the value in server side of 'Scheda.Provenienza' is empty

Please help me...is very important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER:** *This answer may not solve the problem, but I am forced to post it as an answer because I don't have enough reputation to post comments.*

What I want you to do first is define AJAX request type. So, you need this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', // or, type: 'GET', depending on your controller. If you ask me, POST is the right request type to use here, because you want to submit data.
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'AddProducts', // in what controller is this function located? Is this the right path to the function?
    data: data,
    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        // update command is executed.
    }
});
```

Now, the second issue is in the controllers parameter, where you expect to receive `PartnerProduct` model, but from AJAX you don't send any model. In other words, from AJAX you are sending an `object`, and C# does not how to convert it in `PartnerProduct`. Because of this reason, I will ask you to check out the following links, which I think will solve your problem:

- [link one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370062/posting-json-data-via-jquery-to-asp-net-mvc-4-controller-action)
- [link two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object)

If this does not help, ping me in comment so we can look further step by step.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. I think that the function addProducts is correctly located...in debug mode i can access it correctly. The only problem is how to pass the value of data in this example. I have only one object for time and the PartnerProduct object in the function in the controller has the value for the first table correctly definited from the data attribute. So, i don't understand how to pass value also for the second foreign table related with entity framework, but if i have a mode to pass an array of data is the same for me. Thank you

Comment: Have you checked the links I provided? It is explained there with codes how to do it, I don't want to repeat the same code over again. Please try what is written there, and let me know if that worked.